# Annotation not working in Kotlin, wrong init?

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations

I am working in a small feature for a Kotlin project and I am trying to do an annotation.

I want to "encapsulate" a method inside a try catch.

Lets say I annotate a method like this

```
@LogException
fun foo(){
   //do something
}
```

So I want to process the annotation to later do something like this:

```
try{
  foo()
}catch(exception: Exception){
  // do something
  //log
}
```

Is it even possible?

I started with tutorial for Kotlin (that should not be so different than Java) https://medium.com/@elye.project/annotation-tutorial-for-dummies-in-kotlin-1da864acc442 But then I am using this

```
@AutoService(Processor::class)
```

To register my processor and I think is not initializing my annotation.

So far this is my code:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@Documented
annotation class LogException(
    val name: String,
    val statusCode: Int = 500
)
```

and my processor:

```
@AutoService(Processor::class)
class MyProcessor : AbstractProcessor() {

    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyProcessor::class.java)

    override fun process(annotations: MutableSet<out TypeElement>?, roundEnv: RoundEnvironment?): Boolean {
       //do something
        logger.info("info")
        return false
    }

    override fun getSupportedAnnotationTypes(): MutableSet<String> {
        logger.info("info")
        return mutableSetOf(LogException::class.java.canonicalName)
    }

}
```

At the moment I am not able to see any in my logs, or even if I change it for an exception.

I am using this annotation in a method.

```
@LogException
fun foo(){
//do something
}
```

Any idea what Im missing?

//do something and //log something is just example to dont paste all code

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change the existing code using annotation processors. They can only create *new* files. If you want to change *existing* ones, [write Kotlin compiler plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-GMlaziIyo).

If you only want to get rid of boilerplate catch blocks, use an `inline` function which wraps an original function with `try-catch`:

```
inline fun runLogging(code: () -> Unit) = try {
    code()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    yourLogger.log(e)
}

fun foo() = runLogging {
    throw Exception() // will be logged
}
```

Or you can make `runLogging` generic function which handles only specified exceptions:

```
inline fun <reified E : Exception> runLogging(code: () -> Unit) = try {
    code()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    if (e is E) yourLogger.log(e)
    else throw e
}

fun foo() = runLogging<FileNotFoundException> {
    throw FileNotFoundException() // will be logged
}

fun bar() = runLogging<FileNotFoundException> {
    throw Exception() // will be rethrown
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, //do something is of course, just an example where goes my code. I tried couple of things , logger or even throw exceptions without success... any idea why?

Comment: @jpganz18 Please reread my answer. I've said that you **can't** use annotation processors for **editing** the existing code. You can only check it and create new files. If you want to edit code, [write Kotlin compiler plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-GMlaziIyo). If you just want to get rid of boilerplate `catch` blocks, use my solution.